# Passing a mock through a factory in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, factory, googletest

I am using GoogleTest to create a unit test in my project. I want to mock a specific object implementing the following interface :

```
class IMockableObject
{
public:
  IMockable();
  IMockable(const IMockable &other); // copy constructor
  virtual ~IMockable();
  virtual int DoSomething() = 0;
  std::mutex UnCopyableMember;
};
```

I created two classes inheriting this interface. The first one is the real object (it has its own implementation in a cpp file) :

```
class MainImplementation : public IMockable
{
public:
  MainImplementation();
  MainImplementation(const MainImplementation &other);
  virtual int DoSomething();
};
```

The second one is the mock (implementations of constructors are in a cpp file):

```
class MockImplementation : public IMockable
{
public:
  MockImplementation();
  MockImplementation(const MockImplementation &other);
  MOCK_METHOD0(DoSomething, int());
};
```

The unit test I am creating is testing a method which creates a new instance of the `IMockable` and then calls `DoSomething`. The object calling this method takes a factory as argument in its constructor to instantiate the `IMockable`.

ClassToTest.cpp :

```
ClassToTest::ClassToTest(std::function<std::unique_ptr<IMockable>()> factory)
{
    this->factory = factory;
}

void ClassToTest::MethodToTest()
{
    std::unique_ptr<IMockable> object = this->factory();
    object->DoSomething();
    //...
}
```

Now that all my object are defined, here is the test :

```
TEST(FactoryTest, DoSomethingIsCalled)
{
    MockImplementation mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoSomething())
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    auto factory = [mock]() 
    { 
        return std::make_unique<MockImplementation>(mock); 
    };

    ClassToTest object(factory);
    object.MethodToTest();
}
```

I expect the test to pass, because the factory should get the previously created mock, and call `MethodToTest` on it. But the test fails, and I get the following output from google Mock :

> GMOCK WARNING: Uninteresting mock function call - returning default
>   value.
>       Function call: MethodToTest()

It seems that the factory gets the mock but ignores its assertion. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do:

```
TEST(FactoryTest, DoSomethingIsCalled)
{
    auto factory = []()
    { 
        auto mock = std::make_unique<MockImplementation>();
        EXPECT_CALL(*mock, DoSomething()).Times(AtLeast(1));
        return mock; 
    };

    ClassToTest object(factory);
    object.MethodToTest();
}
```

Your method does copies of mocked object, but only the original has the expectation. (expectations are not copied/shared).

Comment: Where does the copy append?

Comment: You capture by copy (1st copy), and you create a `std::unique_ptr` by copy constructor `std::make_unique<MockImplementation>(mock)` (2nd copy).